# Convert UIEvent timestamp to UNIX date

Tags: objective-c

I use touchbegin function like

```
-(void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event;
{

  touchStartTime = [event timestamp];
  NSLog(@"Time of touch is %f ", touchStartTime);
}
```

but I would like to compare it with

`double timeToCompare = [[NSDate date] timeIntervalSince1970];`

but the format is not compatible (timestamp has some other reference point). How do I convert `[event timestamp]` to normal NSDate or vice versa?

Comment: Looks messy to do that; what are you trying to achieve?

Comment: I'm making an app where milliseconds matter, and I'm right now trying to compare how accurate is NSDate compared to UIEvent timestamp (because server the app will be communicating with works with UNIX timestamp)

Answer (score 0):

As [event timestamp] is related to the system up time, you can get the [NSProcessInfo systemUptime] and get the current system time at the same time and go from there.

```
[[NSDate date] timeIntervalSince1970] - [NSProcessInfo systemUptime] + [event timestamp] == [compareDate timeIntervalSince1970]
```

(Well, I don't sign this in blood. Never tried it myself.)

Answer (score 0):

Given that `[UIEvent timestamp]` is the number of seconds since the system was started, one approach to record the first event's timestamp and use that as a reference.

```
@interface MyClass ()
{
    BOOL _haveFirstTimestamp;
    NSTimeInterval _firstTimestamp;
    NSTimeInterval _firstTimestampTime;
}
@end

...

-(void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event;
{
    NSTimeInterval timestamp = [event timestamp];
    if (!_haveFirstTimestamp) {
        _haveFirstTimestamp = YES;
        _firstTimestamp = timestamp;
        _firstTimestampTime  = [[NSDate date] timeIntervalSince1970];
    }

    NSTimestamp timeSince1970 = timestamp - _firstTimestamp + _firstTimestampTime;

    NSLog(@"Time of touch is %f ", timeSince1970);
}
```